# how to get back the previous : command and be able to edit or re-execute in vim

Tags: vim

I typed a command, like

```
:%s/^/d
```

or

```
:!grep ...
```

etc., and I want to quickly get it back and be able to edit or re-execute in vim. Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you have a vimrc and you are in nocompatible mode.

All you need to is press up after you type a `:` to see previously executed commands

If you don't have a vimrc file create the file `.vimrc` in your home directory and put
`set nocompatible` in it.

Another way is to use the command-line-window which you can get to with `q:` This window allows you to edit commands using the normal vim editing commands. For more information about the command-line-window take a look at [`:h command-line-window`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#command-line-window)

Comment: You can also hit `<CTRL-f>` inside ex-mode to get to the command-line-window. Sometimes you maybe use `:<up><up>...` and then realize that you have to edit the command. Hitting `<CTRL-f>` in that case is nice.

Answer (score 2):

Try the up arrow after you type in `:`

Answer (score 0):

How about Ctrl+p after you type in `:` ?

Answer (score 0):

To just re-execute the last command, use `@:`